# Line numbers missing from exception stack trace when ASP.NET impersonation enabled

Tags: asp.net, exception, impersonation, stack-trace

An ASP.NET 2.0 web application has been compiled with PDB symbols, deployed to a server running IIS 6.

In the web.config, [user impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is enabled:

```
  <identity impersonate="true" />
```

When an Exception is thrown, the stack trace is missing line numbers, making it very difficult to determine exactly where the exception is emanating from. eg.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.    at
>   MyApp.ReportingServices.WebForm.DA.AmoRepository.GetDimensions(String
>   perspective)

The login being used to access the website has no special rights or group membership on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get a detailed stack dump for the exception by assigning the '[Debug Programs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787339%28WS.10%29.aspx)' user right to the particular login.

Once the exception was diagnosed I removed that user from that assignment.