# asp.net error shows byte offsets instead of line numbers, EVEN in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, error-handling

In my deployed .NET 3.5/ASP.NET web application, error stack traces always show byte offsets to native code and not line numbers:

```
...
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +61
MyApp.prLoadData() +3931                             <--should show line number
MyApp.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1378    <--should show line number
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
...
```

Things I've already thoroughly checked:

- The application binary is compiled in debug mode.
- I have "Generate Debug Info" set to "Full"
- The application pdb file is deployed to the bin directory and has the same creation timestamp as the dll file.
- Setting compilation="true" in web.config makes no difference.
- Unchecking "Enable Optimizations" makes no difference.

This particular server is owned by the IT department and I have no access to it, nor any knowledge of machine level overrides.  Still, I would have expected ASP.NET to use the pdb files, but it isn't doing it.

Does anyone know what's going on here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your IT department actually deployed the pdb files?  I think you need to have a sit down with them.

Comment: Yes, I can see the files there.  When I said I had no access, I meant to IIS and the server file system.  I can see my own app directory, and the pdb file is in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after a lot of research, I found the answer here on SO: [IIS not giving line numbers in stack trace even though pdb present](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2673623/349974).

For convenience, I'll summarize the answer here.  If you have

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

in your web.config file, this disables line numbers in stack tracing (unless you grant the impersonated user Debug rights).  I took that out and now I get line numbers.

Just goes to show you that the words you use to phrase the problem can really make a difference in whether you match an existing answered question **on the exact same thing!**